# Finding the list of unsatisfied constraints in the Choco model

Tags: choco

Is there a function in choco that retrieves the list of unsatisfied constraints in the model?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such function. The search process stops as soon as a constraint is unsatisfiable or as soon as a constraint has emptied the domain of a variable. Therefore, whenever a fail happens, there is no guarantee whatsoever on the variables' domains, which make things difficult to retrieve the list of unsatisfied constraints. The best you can do is to retrieve the list of propagators and check their status using the isEntailed() function.